# Gradle: Jar Task doesn't include Files with unknown extensions

Tags: java, jar, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to build the `library.jar` for a custom programming language of mine. The library contains both Java classes and classes written in the language. I already managed to compile the compiler, run it on these classes and produce the output files in a folder called `dbin`.

```
- src
  - ...
- build
  - ...
- dbin
  - Foo.class
  - Custom.dyo   // <- the new file type
- build.gradle
```

What I am trying to achieve is to copy all files in the `dbin` directory to the Jar file, and I tried this with the following script:

```
task buildLib(type: Jar, dependsOn: [ 'classes', 'compileDyvilLibrary' ]) {
    from sourceSets.library.output

    // Include Compiler Output
    from fileTree(dir: 'dbin', includes: [ '**/*.class', '**/*.dyo' ])

    baseName = 'dyvil-library'
}
```

The problem is that although it is explicitly included, the jar file does not contain any `.dyo` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `from` line is executed at configuration time, (i.e. before any task is run) If the files do not exist in the dir location you specified when the `fileTree` is instantiated then it will not contain any files.

You can try solving this by making `from` method do a a lazy evaluation:

```
from { fileTree(dir: 'dbin', includes: [ '**/*.class', '**/*.dyo' ]) }
```

You might also want to try this syntax:

```
from ('dbin') {
    include '**/*.class'
    include '**/*.dyo'
}
```